# Can't double-click to open Google Sheet document (Windows with File Stream)

Tags: windows-10, google-drive, google-drive-file-stream

I use Google Drive File Stream on Windows. I used to be able to open a Google spreadsheet from an explorer window just by double-clicking on it like any other file. Now I can only open them by right-clicking on the document and choosing "Open with Google Drive File Stream".

[image: screen capture]

If I right-click and choose "Open with..." I get this; I've already checked "Always use this app to open .gsheet files."

[image: screen capture]

The entry in "Choose default apps by file type" is correct:

[image]

Is this something specific to my setup, or is this a change that affects all users?

Comment: Could you add to the post the contents of the following registry keys: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.gsheet`, `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.gsheet`, including their sub-key `OpenWithProgids`.

Comment: Remark: The [documentation](https://gsuite.google.com/learning-center/products/drive/get-started/#!/section-3-2) doesn't promise double-click support in Windows. Giving the above information as requested might help.

Comment: What happens now if you double click?

Comment: @harrymc - Documentation desn't promise this feature, but the OP mentions that it was working before... something must have changed.

Comment: You could try removing from the registry the file extension associations, and see what happens.

Comment: @sancho.s: It's clear that Google has changed something. The idea is to force it back to the previous behavior, but that's impossible without cooperation from the OP.

Comment: @harrymc - I apologize, I was traveling and didn't see these comments. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.gsheet` doesn't exist. `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.gsheet` contains `GoogleDriveFS.gsheet`.

Comment: @harrymc - I've added `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.gsheet` and set it to `GoogleDriveFS.gsheet` and it works now. If you'll post this as an answer I can give you the bounty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should ensure that the following registry keys exist and have as their value
`GoogleDriveFS.gsheet`:

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.gsheet`
- `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.gsheet`

Comment: I've started a new bounty, I can award it in 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

See the known issue [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7337638?hl=en&vid=0-848458258916-1552580809182).

The following limitations and known issues apply to the current release:

- Some file types cannot be stored in Team Drives, such as:

  - Google Maps
  - Google Photos
  - Some virtual file types, such as App Maker apps
  - Owned by other domains
- External users can only be added as a Team Drives member if they have a Google account associated with their email address.

Follow discussion [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/y5ODKWfoZY4) on this same issue.

---

One other workaround is [here](https://superuser.com/a/1042285/764067).

## Edit:

Apps for Specific File Types:

> The Chrome Web Store is full of handy applications you can link with Google Drive. Some of these apps will open specific file types like PDFs. Think of it like how your computer can open music files in all sorts of different media players.
>
> If you have apps installed and want to set an app to be the default for opening a certain type of file, that’s easy to change. Login to Google Drive, click the Cog icon, click Settings, then Manage apps.
>
> Scroll to the app you wish to manage and tick the Use by default checkbox. Of course, simply untick this box to remove the default.

Ref: [8 Google Drive Settings You Should Change Right Now](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/google-drive-settings-change/)

Comment: That's not the issue. These are garden-variety gsheet and gdoc documents.

Comment: @HerbCaudill see my edit if that helps.