# How to open a local office file stored in Google Drive (docs, sheets etc.) directly?

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-office, sync, windows-11, google-drive

I have Google Drive installed. I'd like to open local Office files inside Google Drive directly in Google Drive, that would save me an expensive subscription to Microsoft 365 Office suit. I don't want to do this from the browser, rather from the regular Windows 11 File explorer. Hence, how to do that, I could not find an answer online.

1. Files are stored/synced/streamed using Google Drive on my computer - meaning there is a corresponding file saved in the cloud (using Google Drive)
2. I want to open these files ending with docx or xlsx using the appropriate Google Drive programme online. Not as a copy, but just as a synced files as they are.

Any help appreciated.

EDIT: on Google I searched for ways to open files locally, but all I could find were ways to open files local files from within Google Drive (web-based) by uploading them. I found no way to just double-click on a docx file on my computer (in a Drive folder) and that it opens in the browser as a Google Docs rendered file.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to show what you've searched for when you could not find an answer online? I found something that might work, but I don't know what you've tried so far, so don't know if it's worth writing an answer for.

Comment: Did this article help you? https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9617/how-to-open-local-documents-directly-in-google-docs

Comment: I see a similar question is being asked, but the question was asked over 12 years ago, so I guess things have moved on. The accepted answer seems to be outdated, and other answers as well. So far no solution.

Comment: The question from [webapps.se] that is 12 years old was not related to Office files and most of the responses were link only and most of those the links are broken, obsolete or the content have changed to much. The question requires too much work to be "updated" so I closed it (I'm a mod in [webapps.se].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open doc, ppt, or xls files with Google Drive with double clicks from my desktop?](https://superuser.com/questions/1038790/how-to-open-doc-ppt-or-xls-files-with-google-drive-with-double-clicks-from-my)

Comment: @Rubén-PeopleFirst yes, could you add it as an answer, I can then close the question, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use this Chrome extension from Google [Office Editing for Docs, Sheets & Slides](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/office-editing-for-docs-s/gbkeegbaiigmenfmjfclcdgdpimamgkj?hl=en)

> Once the extension is installed, Office files that you drag into Chrome, open in Gmail, Google Drive, and more, will be opened in Docs, Sheets, and Slides for viewing and editing.

According to the Chrome Webstore Listing for this Chrome extension, it was updated on January 23, 2023.

Note: Few moments ago I found this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1042285/152004) to [How to open doc, ppt, or xls files with Google Drive with double clicks from my desktop?](https://superuser.com/q/1038790/152004) that suggest the same Chrome extension.

Related

- [Office editing mode is now the default editing mode for Office files in Drive on the web](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2020/10/office-editing-default-google-drive-docs.html) from Google Workspace Updates, posted in 2020.
- [Work with Microsoft Office files](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9406611) from the Google Docs Help Center.